# How do I get a file's path in PHP?

Tags: php, string, file, path

I have to check using the file_exists function...
But, if I use something like that

```
if (file_exists('http://horabola.com/imagens/dt_2845.jpg')) {
  //code
}
```

it doesn't work...

I know and I'm sure that the file "dt_2845.jpg" exists in the folder "imagens" ....
now, how do I check that? How do I get the server's file path?

Comment: is this picture on your server or on a different website?

Comment: HTTP Stream Wrappers do not support the stat() family of functions to which `file_exists` belongs. See the [Tip box in the manual](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and the mentioned links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/imagens/dt_2845.jpg')) {
  //code
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The server's filesystem path for url / is stored in the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` [predefined variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

The current script's path is always stored in the `__FILE__` constant. You may want to use

```
 dirname(__FILE__);
```

to know the current script's filesystem path.

What you tried by calling:

```
file_exists('http://horabola.com/imagens/dt_2845.jpg');
```

which is open files via HTTP, needs the use of [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) instead of file_exists() (thanks @Gordon for pointing this out), and you need, on your PHP server, the so-called url wrapper for [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php). Anyway, using the HTTP protocol to open files on the same server as the runnning script is a bit of a performance waste (using HTTP, that is network, instead of hard disk, that is 10x to 1000x faster).

Comment: please see my comment below the question for `file_exists` and URLs.